# Flutter#7 RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to print out a list of images

```
    Future<void> getDeviceImage() async {
    var api = TechAPI.shared;
    var res = await api.getDeviceImage();
    var dataResponse = DataResponse.fromJson(res);
    print(dataResponse.toJson());
    List<dynamic> dt = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dataResponse.data));
    print(dt);
    list.add(dt);
  }
```

```
List<dynamic> list = [];
list[0]; // <-- Error since there's no element at index 0 in the list.
```

I will get an error which is :

```
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)
```

However when I hot - reload in VS code. my list just returns data

How can I fix this without having to hot-reload it.

Comment: Can you include how you are using `getDeviceImage`?

Comment: Why don't you use the same ```list``` and assign the response value to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help :

Initialize the list as :

`List<dynamic> list=[];`

Your function:

```
Future<void> getDeviceImage() async {
var api = TechAPI.shared;
await api.getDeviceImage().then((res){
var dataResponse = DataResponse.fromJson(res);
print(dataResponse.toJson());
setState((){
list =List<dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dataResponse.data)));
 });
});
    }
```

Comment: I just tried it with `List<dynamic> dt = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dataResponse.data));
    print(dt);
    list.add(dt);` and add `setState(() {
      
    });` and it works fine

Comment: Yes, ```setState``` was the issue in this case because the ```build()``` won't get executed unless you call ```setState```. Why are you using an additional list ```dt``` when one list can serve the purpose? Using an additional variable unnecessarily will slow down the app in the long run.

Comment: i just want to print out the data by assigning it to dt. that's my bad habit

Comment: But refrain from it unless its absolutely necessary.